# Linking email button to actual email

Tags: html

I trying to link my email to a HTML button I created and I liked but not sure how to link it without creating another hyperlink. Here is my code:

```
    <div class="row heading red-text text-accent-2">

        <div class="col-md">enter code here

            <h1>Contact Me</h1>

            <hr class="col-md">

        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col s12">

            <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn">E-mail</a>

        </div>

    </div>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: you want to keep your email id in **To**?

Comment: you want to link it without `href=" "`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mailto:` and pass your email value in `href` property of `<a>` tag. As shown in below code.

```html
<div class="row heading red-text text-accent-2">

        <div class="col-md">enter code here

            <h1>Contact Me</h1>

            <hr class="col-md">

        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col s12">

            <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn" href="mailto:abc@example.com">E-mail</a>

        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: @QFrank82, Did my answer help to solved your problem?